# Matching up form post array values after form submission in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

with multiple selection inputs

```
<select class="form-control" id="location" name="location[]" >
<option selected disabled value="">Choose Location</option>
<option value="closing">Closing Station</option>
<option value="device">Device/ROF</option>
<option value="merch1">General Merch 1</option>
<option value="merch2">General Merch 2</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="image_name[]" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
```

I have this array upon form submission:

```
Array (
    [location] => Array (
    [0] => closing 
    [1] => merch1 
    [2] => merch2 ) 

    [image] => Array ( 
    [0] => AL-AL.jpg 
    [1] => AL-AN.jpg 
    [2] => AL-AV.jpg 
    [3] => AL-CA.jpg 
    [4] => AL-CL.jpg 
    [5] => AL-CM.jpg ) 

    [submit] => Submit 
)
```

I want the output in PHP to be like this: location[0] and image[0], etc:
this is my code:

```
<?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                 foreach ($_POST['location'] as $location) {
                foreach ($_POST['image_name'] as $image) {
    echo "you have selected $image to go to this location: $location <br/>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
?>
```

This is currently outputting:

```
you have selected AL-AL.jpg to go to this location: closing 
you have selected AL-AN.jpg to go to this location: closing 
you have selected AL-AV.jpg to go to this location: closing 
you have selected AL-CA.jpg to go to this location: closing 
you have selected AL-CL.jpg to go to this location: closing 
you have selected AL-CM.jpg to go to this location: closing 
you have selected AL-AL.jpg to go to this location: merch2 
you have selected AL-AN.jpg to go to this location: merch2 
you have selected AL-AV.jpg to go to this location: merch2 
you have selected AL-CA.jpg to go to this location: merch2 
you have selected AL-CL.jpg to go to this location: merch2 
you have selected AL-CM.jpg to go to this location: merch2
```

it just seems to be an eternal loop right now. I know there is a way to match up each array on the []values and then only output where there are matches, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

no need for the 2 loops, use the key from location to find the image

```
<?php
$p['location'][0]='closing'; 
$p['location'][1]='merch1';
$p['location'][2]='merch2'; 

$p['image'][0]='AL-AL.jpg'; 
$p['image'][1]='AL-AN.jpg'; 
$p['image'][2]= 'AL-AV.jpg'; 

foreach($p['location'] as $k=>$v ){
echo "you have selected ".$p['image'][$k]." to go to this location: $v <br/>";
}

?>
```

Output:

> you have selected AL-AL.jpg to go to this location: closing 
>  you
>   have selected AL-AN.jpg to go to this location: merch1 
>  you have
>   selected AL-AV.jpg to go to this location: merch2

Comment: This solution doesn't work right, it always matches the first image with any of the dropdown choices. Is there a way to match the selections [location][0] - [image][0], etc. as shown in the array?

Comment: @user1559189 i have rewritten the answer with included values, hope that helps. there are some inconstancies in the question but i think the above should solve it.